# stumbled in using ZwOpenFile

Tags: c, api, winapi, file, file-io

I have to open a file using ZwOpenFile API. This is my requirement. When I set the path in object name parameter. I could see fields Length and maximumlength in the object name.

Length is just length of the path and I usually keep maximumlength as the value of Length.

It worked mostly, however some times it doesnot work. In some cases I solved it via maximumlength  = length *2. Even this computation doesn't work for few other cases.

I am very much puzzled with the Maximumlength value computation.

Can some one help.

Comment: Are you using RtlInitUnicodeString to initialise your string?

Comment: I am changing the incoming file path. hence the lengths were changed. I used to compute it via rtlunicodestring(the rite way). But it is not contextually the same. Then through wine codes, i found once we are editing the file path name we have to convert it to ntfilepathname(/??/). For that we have to use RTL_dospathnametontpathname_u. Which automatically givces us the unicode string. that conversion worked out. Thnaks for your interest

Comment: Why are you using ZwOpenFile?  What functionality does it provide that CreateFile doesn't also provide?

Comment: Please post your failing code - identifying the problem is guesswork without it

Comment: Larry, I append a virtual path in the incoming path of zwopenfile. hence I have to edit the object attribute in it.

Comment: steve,using rtlunicodestring and rtldospathnametontpathname_u solved the problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at UNICODE_STRING structure definition: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380518%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Length is wcslen(str.Buffer) * sizeof(WCHAR) ==  * 2

MaximumLength field may be Length + sizeof(WCHAR) == Length + 2

ZwOpenFile will not write to this string, so we shouldn't care about capacity of string.

Comment: I append a virtual path in the incoming path of zwopenfile. hence I have to edit the object attribute in it. However the calculation you have shown will work. thanks

Comment: I hooked zwopenfile. hence i will be inside the implementation, to edit its parameter to my need.

Answer (score 0):

Initially i converted the ntpath name manually with /??/. this was not worked out.

Then I tried it using RTL_dospathnametontpathname_u, which yielded me an unicode string.
Then it is worked for my case.
Also normaly rtlinitunitcodestring api would be used ot initalise as "Will A"
suggested.

Thanks.